# Minecraft RAM allocation

Tags: memory, minecraft, parameters

When I try to allocate more RAM to Minecraft the arguments are:
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M

I don't know what this means, why isn't it just "-Xmx1g", what is the purpose of everything else in there?

Comment: From a quick search, some of it seems to be 'cargo cult' type recommendations- passed round and passed on without any explanation. These are launch options to tune various aspects of the JVM (see for example [this answer over at Arquade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190443).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're switches for your java process. UseConcMarkSweepGC & CMSIncrementalMode for example are settings for the garbage collector (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). I don't think they're very useful.

To add more RAM to your process '-Xmx1G' to '-Xmx2G' is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a MAX amount of RAM Change -Xmx1G to -Xmx and then the number of ram you want and then the unit, so for 512 MB do -Xmx512M and for 8 GB do -Xmx8G. If you want to change the minimum amount of RAM, add another argument -Xms1G, but replace 1G with the same unit type as before.

Answer (score -2):

where are you using **-Xmx1g** replace with **-Xmx1G -Xms2G**
you can also read article for understand more easy (http://www.howtominecraft.net/allocate-ram-minecraft/)

Comment: Don't link an answer, explain it here instead as the linked information may go away.